Diy puppy pee pads
What are some cost-effective DIY puppy pee pads? I am not trying to keep washing blankets and purchasing disposable pee pads are too expensive at the moment

The traditional solution for this (predating pee pads by a very long time) is multiple layers of newspaper.  If you have a lot of puppies (like a full litter or more than one litter), it helps to establish a contact with someone at the local distribution center for a major paper like the Wall Street Journal, as they'll discard overprints daily and are often happy to dispose of (some of) them without having to pay to have them removed.
